# Is it possible to selectively set modules for components in Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: analyticsModule must be set`

I'm building a library that uses template-style initialization. The user can selectively setup modules for the project with that library. It uses Dagger 2 for DI.

But Dagger 2 doesn't seem to allow optional modules. Can't unset modules be simply ignored?

Comment: Parametrized modules need to be set manually, while non-parametrized modules are automatically created if not provided through the builder. You would probably need some kind of factory method to provide "empty modules" if they don't exist. But maybe you can customize this behavior through the `@Component.Builder` annotation that was added in the latest snapshot.

Comment: Can't the module creation be skipped entirely? I will also see the annotation that you have mentioned.
Using empty constructors now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using Multibindings, which allows for users to optionally add in dependencies into a `Set<T>` or `Map<K,V>`. Here's an example:

```
interface Plugin {
    void install(Application application);
}

@Component({ModuleA.class, ModuleB.class})
interface PluginComponent {
    Set<Plugin> plugins();
}

@Module
class ModuleA {
    @Provides(type = SET) Plugin providFooPlugin() {
        return new FooPlugin();
    }
}

@Module
class ModuleB {
    @Provides(type = SET) Plugin providBarPlugin() {
        return new BarPlugin();
    }
}
```

In this case, you still need an instance of each module, even if it's not used. One option to get around this would be to use `@Provides(type = SET_VALUES)`, and have modules that you wan't turned off to return `Collections.emptySet()`. Here's a modified example:

```
interface Plugin {
    void install(Application application);
}

@Component({ModuleA.class, ModuleB.class})
interface PluginComponent {
    Set<Plugin> plugins();
}

@Module
class ModuleA {
    private final Set<Plugin> plugins;

    ModuleA(Set<Plugin> plugins) {
        this.plugins = plugins;
    }

    @Provides(type = SET_VALUES) Plugin providFooPlugins() {
        return plugins;
    }
}

@Module
class ModuleB {
    @Provides(type = SET) Plugin providBarPlugin() {
        return new BarPlugin();
    }
}
```

Now, you can call:

```
DaggerPluginComponent.builder()
    .moduleA(new ModuleA(Collections.emptySet())
    .build();
```

Or alternatively:

```
Set<Plugin> plugins = new HashSet<>();
plugins.add(new AwesomePlugin());
plugins.add(new BoringPlugin());
DaggerPluginComponent.builder()
    .moduleA(new ModuleA(plugins)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This looks like a nice approach, but will Dagger be able to inject dependencies on the basis of their exact types?

Comment: Not sure I get the question. Are you asking if this works for non-interface types? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Well, if you see in `ModuleA` or even `ModuleB`, you can see that the provisions are of type `Plugin`, but when I request for `FooPlugin` explicitly, will Dagger know which to provide?

Comment: You can `@Provides FooPlugin provideFooPlugin()` (or even just mark the constructor with `@Inject`) and then separately add that to the multibindings  with `@Provides(type = SET)`. If you want to easily retrieve a particular type but also inject the full set, you can consider using `type = MAP`. Read more about it here: http://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!